# Equation of tangent plane for a differentiable $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

If $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Then the equation of the tangent line at a point $x_0$ is given by
$$y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0).$$
Here if you put $x=x_0$, you get $y=f(x_0)$. So the tangent line serves its purpose of approximating the curve with a linear map at the point $x_0$.

If $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Then the equation of the tangent plane at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by
$$z=f(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x}(x-x_0)+\frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial y}(y-y_0).$$
Here too we see at the point $(x_0, y_0)$ we get $z=f(x_0.y_0)$.

What is the above counterpart or a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ which is differentiable? Is it called a tangent plane or a tangent surface? Is it a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$? What would be its equation?

Answer (score 1):

For any differentiable function $f\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^m$ you will have precise the same formula. Now every term on the right-hand side is a vector in $\Bbb R^m$ and you add the three vectors. The tangent plane is a $2$-dimensional plane in $\Bbb R^{m+2}$.

**EDIT**: In particular, if $f(x,y) = \big(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),\dots, f_m(x,y)\big)$, then you just differentiate component by component. So your tangent plane will be given by
\begin{align*}
z_1 &= \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0) \\
z_2 &= \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0) \\
&\vdots \\
z_m &= \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0).
\end{align*}

Comment: could you please be a bit more elaborate.

Comment: Hi. I have edited my question for more clarity. Could you please answer those questions?